# SQL always returning same results

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm trying to do a search on a table in my database where it returns the top 50 rows with a firstname like the search term being passed to the function, but its always returning the same 50 results

My sql looks like this:

```
Select TOP(50) * 
FROM [database].[dbo].[records] 
WHERE (A_1STNAME LIKE '" + @searchTerm + "%') 
ORDER BY A_RECID
```

When I run this query in Visual Studios query window, it works as expected but when I run it through my ASP.NET application, it always returns the same 50 results, and only one of them has a first name close to the searchTerm I passed to it.

here is the page code that runs the function:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        _migrated_data data = new _migrated_data();
        DataSet ds = data.Search(Request.QueryString.Get("query"), "A_RECID", 50);
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            rpt_Data.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            rpt_Data.DataBind();
        }

}
```

and here is the search method of _migrated_data:

```
public DataSet Search(String @pSearchTerm, String @pSortBy, int @pRowCount)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbConnection objOleDBConn;
    OleDbDataAdapter objOleDBDa;
    objOleDBConn = new OleDbConnection(ClearingHouse_OLEDDB);
    objOleDBConn.Open();
    string lSQL = "SELECT TOP(50) * FROM [database].[dbo].[records]";
    lSQL += " WHERE (A_1STNAME LIKE @searchTerm ) ORDER BY @sortBy";
    SqlCommand t = new SqlCommand(lSQL);

    if (pSearchTerm != null && pSearchTerm != "")
    {
        t.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchTerm", @pSearchTerm + "%");
    }

    if (pSortBy != null && pSortBy != "")
    {
        t.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sortBy", @pSortBy);
    }
    else
    {
        t.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sortBy", "A_RECID");
    }
    objOleDBDa = new OleDbDataAdapter(t.CommandText, objOleDBConn);
    objOleDBDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    objOleDBDa.Fill(ds);
    objOleDBConn.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

Using locals to view the final CommandText of t, I get the sql results I gave above.

Any help is greatly appriciated :)

Comment: Are you sure that your application passed valid SQL? I mean did you use SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(...

Comment: Are you sure the search term isn't hard-coded somewhere in your asp page?

Comment: Also note your current sql is open to sql injection as you have it. You should pass the search term as a paremeter as @rkosegi suggests.

Comment: I made a quick edit to make the sql more readable (*I realize that it's inline in your code*). As @MikeParkhill said, this leaves your app open to SQL injection... so don't do it. Either use LINQ to SQL (or some other ORM), or [parameterize your query](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-vb) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS Rob Rodi said, first of all, to get the results begining with a value you will need `%` char at the end of the therm:

```
Select TOP(50) * 
FROM [database].[dbo].[records] 
WHERE (A_1STNAME LIKE '" + @searchTerm + "%') 
ORDER BY A_RECID
```

Second, probably your `searchTerm` is empty, so it's grabbing always the same results.

Debug your app and watch the variable to see if it's receiving some value.

Comment: the `%` is exactly the issue. Also, adding another `%` symbol after `@searchTerm` will match a larger amount of records.

Comment: Oops... To match all beginning withe the therm the `%`have to be in the end. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: sorry, I left the % out in my original post but it was in my code, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You are having SQL injection there. Also it looks like the %-signs are missing.

The fact, that the query works in a query window and not in your app means, that the error is not in your query! Did you think about that? Probably, you should post code of your ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your parameter isn't being correctly passed to your data layer.  Easiest way to find out if that's the case is to turn on [Sql Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and check  to see if it's being passed.  If it is, your sql's to blame.  If it's not, it's your application.  You can then use the debugger on your application to work your way up the stack to see where the problem lies.